# Malicious code added without modifying my PHP files

Tags: php, apache, hosting, malware

I just discovered that every website in my hosting account (which is a shared hosting) is infected with malicious code.

The malicious code is a < script> tag appended after the < /html> tag. It redirects to a russian website.

The problem is this: my PHP files are not compromissed. I downloaded them via FTP, and they are fine. The "last modified" dates are fine too (some files are from 2012). Even if I upload a brand new PHP file, when I access it through the web, it's infected. But if I download it again via FTP, it´s fine.

It's like some .htaccess rule is appending the malicious code to all my PHP pages AFTER they pass through the PHP engine, or something like that (but my .htaccess files are fine too).

What could be the problem? Is the hosting provider compromised, or is it my account? What can I do to solve this problem? Google is already sending me malware notifications, and the support guys are slow as hell.

Thanks for your time, and please forgive my poor english.

**Edit:** Adding < ?php exit() ?> to the end of any PHP file stops the infection, so this seems to be a PHP problem.

Comment: Is it a shared hosting, if yes then some free sharing servers add/inject advertisement...marketing strategy so you can buy a subscription

Comment: Yes, it's a shared hosting.

Comment: Is this a CMS or wordpress type site?

Comment: Some of my domains run CMS like Wordpress, some don't. Each PHP file on each of my domains is served with the malicious code, even test files I just wrote and uploaded.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the hosting company to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, wouldn't hurt to change your ftp password, also look for files that aren't yours or part of the installation. I've had issue like that before and there were scripts in the `images` directory that I didn't put there. I removed them. Change any files so that they aren't world writeable. e.g. change from `666` to `644`. Do the same to directories, `777` to `755`. If the files and directories are owned by the ftp user the lesser permissions should be fine.

Then maybe try this to clean up or get your host to do it if you don't have access.

http://cachecrew.com/fixing-an-infected-php-web-server/

Comment: the link appears dead!?

Comment: Works for me. I just tried it again.

Comment: not the place to discuss it, but i can't access the link, the site yes, but not that particular link..

Comment: "Link" itself worked fine for me. @Tio

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do, is change the FTP password, and run an anti-virus on the computer you are using to access the FTP.

Something like this has happened to me before, and the point of intrusion on the web server was trough the stealing of the FTP user and password trough a trojan.

About the PHP files, and in the start of the file, aren't their any strange  tag?

In my case, the files were updated on the start on the file, and it wasn't only PHP files, HTML files were also affected.

The script tag that appear after the  tag, could be inserted their trough Javascript. And don't rely on the date modified ( check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3029618/201806) )